# Find the value of the constant k that makes the function continuous

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

h(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^{2}  & \text{if $x\le5$} \\
x+k &  \text{if $x>\ 5$} \\
\end{cases}

Answer choices are A. k=20 B.k=-5 C. k=5 D. k=30

Comment: What is your choice and why?

Comment: I believe that the answer is A. k=20 as I utilized a similar format from a previous question I had to do on this assignment to see that I would plug the 5 into x^2 and then set that equation = to 5+k. After doing that I was left with 25=5+k and then finally k=20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 5-}x^2=\lim_{x\to 5+}x+k$$$$5^2=5+k$$$$k=20$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that a function $f(x)$ is continuous if $\lim_{x\to  a}f(x)=f(a)$, means that the global limit as $x$ approches $a$ exists and it's exactly equal to $f(a)$.

The two one-sided limits exist and are equal if the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ exists.

So our condition is: $$\lim_{x\to  5+}h(x)=\lim_{x\to  5-}h(x)=h(5)$$

then it's easy to get the solution as: $$\lim_{x\to  5+}x+k=\lim_{x\to  5-}x^2=5^2$$

so $$k=20$$

and you can redefine your continous function in $R$:

$$h(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^{2}  & \text{if $x\le5$} \\
x+20 &  \text{if $x>\ 5$} \\
\end{cases}$$